Pulseaudio not detecting microphone
I have a pair of Razer Nari Ultimate headphones with an integrated microphone, I never had any issues with them until a couple of days ago when I tried installing droidcam to use my phone's mic on my pc. When i rebooted after installing droidcam my headphone mic disappeared from pavucontrol.
I'm running pulseaudio on ubuntu 23.10
I tried looking at the droidcam sound install script and undone all the changes manually but nothing changed.
arecord -l:
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC887-VD Alt Analog [ALC887-VD Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Ultimate [Razer Nari Ultimate], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

I tried running pactl load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0 after running pulseaudio -vvv and this was printed in the logs:
I: [pulseaudio] client.c: Created 6 "Native client (UNIX socket client)"
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Protocol version: remote 35, local 35
I: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Got credentials: uid=1000 gid=1000 success=1
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: SHM possible: yes
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Negotiated SHM: yes
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Memfd possible: yes
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Negotiated SHM type: shared memfd
D: [pulseaudio] memblock.c: Using shared memfd memory pool with 1024 slots of size 64.0 KiB each, total size is 64.0 MiB, maximum usable slot size is 65472
D: [pulseaudio] srbchannel.c: SHM block is 65472 bytes, ringbuffer capacity is 2 * 32712 bytes
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Enabling srbchannel...
D: [pulseaudio] module-augment-properties.c: Looking for .desktop file for pactl
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Client enabled srbchannel.
D: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Trying hw:1,0 with SND_PCM_NO_AUTO_FORMAT ...
D: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Managed to open hw:1,0
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Cannot disable ALSA period wakeups
D: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Maximum hw buffer size is 2000 ms
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
D: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Set neither period nor buffer size.
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_hw_params failed: No space left on device
D: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Trying hw:1,0 without SND_PCM_NO_AUTO_FORMAT ...
D: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Managed to open hw:1,0
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Cannot disable ALSA period wakeups
D: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Maximum hw buffer size is 2000 ms
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
D: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Set neither period nor buffer size.
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_hw_params failed: No space left on device
D: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Trying plug:SLAVE='hw:1,0' with SND_PCM_NO_AUTO_FORMAT ...
D: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Managed to open plug:SLAVE='hw:1,0'
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Cannot disable ALSA period wakeups
D: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Maximum hw buffer size is 2000 ms
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
D: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Set neither period nor buffer size.
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_hw_params failed: No space left on device
D: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Trying plug:SLAVE='hw:1,0' without SND_PCM_NO_AUTO_FORMAT ...
D: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Managed to open plug:SLAVE='hw:1,0'
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Cannot disable ALSA period wakeups
D: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Maximum hw buffer size is 2000 ms
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
D: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Set neither period nor buffer size.
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE failed (-28)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_hw_params failed: No space left on device
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Failed to set hardware parameters on plug:SLAVE='hw:1,0': No space left on device
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-source" (argument: "device=hw:1,0"): initialization failed.
D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: /dev/snd/controlC1 is accessible: yes
D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Resuming all sinks and sources of card alsa_card.usb-Razer_Razer_Nari_Ultimate-00.
I: [pulseaudio] client.c: Freed 6 "pactl"
I: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Connection died.

These headphones have two outputs, game and chat , and I noticed that if I add load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0 to /etc/pulse/default.pa then the microphone works but the outputs disappear. If i also add load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:1,0 and load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:1,1 for the two outputs then I get the microphone but only one of the two outputs.
aplay -l:
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Ultimate [Razer Nari Ultimate], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Ultimate [Razer Nari Ultimate], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [LC32G5xT]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

I'm not really sure what else I could add to be helpful.
Thanks.
